# Combine only unique values with comma and & separator where ever required

Tags: vba6, excel-2021

I am trying to combine unique values to BB4 to BB5
for eg.
ABCD1, ABCD1, EFGH1, EFGH1 & HIJK1,

result BB5 = ABCD1, EFGH1 & HIJK1
removing the repeated  values and get the combination of unique values with separator comma and "&".

I am using this formula to collect the data from AM

B4= below formula

```
=LET(
    Φ,AM4:AM18,
    SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",,Φ),", "," & ",MAX(1,SUM(N(Φ<>""))-1))
)
```

Now I need to get the unigue values  ABCD1, ABCD1, EFGH1, EFGH1 & HIJK1,

Please help me to achieve this task.